# Sklearn's TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False, norm=None) returns the same output as CountVectorizer()

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to understand the code behind `TfidfTransformer()`. From `sklearn`'s documentation, I can get the term frequencies by setting `use_idf=False`. But when I check the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) on Github, I noticed that the  `TfidfTransformer()` will return the same value as `CountVectorizer()` when not using normalization, which is just the count of each term.

The code that is supposed to calculate term frequencies.

```py
def transform(self, x, copy=True):
"""Transform a count matrix to a tf or tf-idf representation.

Parameters
----------
X : sparse matrix of (n_samples, n_features)
    A matrix of term/token counts.
    
copy : bool, default=True
    Whether to copy X and operate on the copy or perform in-place
    operations.
    
Returns
-------
vectors : sparse matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features)
    Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.
"""
X = self._validate_data(
    X, accept_sparse="csr", dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES, copy-copy, reset=False
)
if not sp.issparse(X):
    X = sp.csr_matrix(X, dtype=np.float64)
    
if self.sublinear_tf:
    np.log(X.data, X.data)
    X.data += 1
    
if self.use_idf:
    # idf being a property, the automatic attributes detection
    # does not work as usual and we need to specify the attribute not fitted")
    # name:
check_is_fitted (self, attributes=["idf_"], msg="idf vector is not fitted")

# *= doesn't work
X = X * self._idf_diag

if self.norm is not None:
    X = normalize(X, norm=self.norm, copy=False)

return X
```

[image of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLjBD.png)

To investigate more, I ran both classes and compared the output of both CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer using the following code and the output is equal.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer


dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, random_state=1, remove=(
    'headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), subset='train', categories=['sci.electronics', 'rec.autos', 'rec.sport.hockey'])
train_documents = dataset.data

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
train_documents_mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_documents)

tf_vectorizer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False, norm=None)
train_documents_mat_2 = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_documents_mat)

equal = np.array_equal(
    train_documents_mat.toarray(),
    train_documents_mat_2.toarray()
)

print(equal)
```

I am trying to get the term frequencies for my documents rather than just the count. Any ideas why `sklearn` implement TF-IDF in this way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please edit your question to include all relevant code, screenshots of code are useless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).